# mongodb search case insensitive not working

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

below is DB

```
[
  {
    "name": "new İSLAND"
  },
  {
    "name": "old İSLAND"
  }
]
```

below is query :

```
db.collection.find({
  "name": {
    "$regex": "İS",
    "$options": "i"
  }
})
```

this brings the result :

```
[
  {
    "_id": ObjectId("5a934e000102030405000000"),
    "name": "new İSLAND"
  },
  {
    "_id": ObjectId("5a934e000102030405000001"),
    "name": "old İSLAND"
  }
]
```

what I want is, below query should bring the results aswell but not bringing:

```
db.collection.find({
  "name": {
    "$regex": "is",
    "$options": "i"
  }
})
```

result: no document found

https://mongoplayground.net/p/_o0CjQqL21H

How can fix it, result should accept case insensitive

Comment: The character `İ` does not look like the capital `I`. It works well with the character replaced like [this](https://mongoplayground.net/p/NlArM21nKlk)

Comment: In my db there are non-english characters like İ , Ü,  etc, how can I fix it.

Comment: Check out the [text search page](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/tutorial/specify-language-for-text-index/) in official doc to get some starting point.